# Time complexity of both the approaches (one is using dict and other list)

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, time-complexity

Question is given an array A and B. Sort B according to order defined by array A. B is a subset of array A.
For eg:

```
Input:
a = [52,23,34,1,98,2,57,6,12,89,176,45, 90, 35 ]
b = [12,52,1,35]
Output = [52, 1, 12, 35]
```

Explanation- since 52 came first in array A therefore we print that first, then came 1 and so on...

**Solution 1 using Hashmap/dictionary in python3:**

```
a = [52,23,34,1,98,2,57,6,12,89,176,45, 90, 35 ]
b = [12,52,1,35]
d ={}
j =0

for i in b:
    d[i]= j
    j = j+1
   

for i in a:
    if i in d:
        print(i)
```

**Solution 2 using array:**

```
a = [52,23,34,1,98,2,57,6,12,89,176,45, 90, 35 ]
b = [12,52,1,35]

for i in a:
    if i in b:
        print(i)
```

So my question is does Solution 1 and Solution 2 have different time complexities?
Or is it O(n^2)
for both the solutions... or is it O(n) for solution 1 and O(n^2) for solution 2... or any other complexity

Comment: *technically* the first solution you have is showing O(n+m) or O(2n) as the first loop takes n iterations and the second loop m, then the time complexity would be O(n + m), while the second solution is O(n) only.

Comment: but isn't the IF statement in solution 2 is O(n) complex.. since that If is basically searching in a list..@FishingCode

Comment: It would be *O(n^2)* if it were a nested for loop, but that is not the case. the best case of finding that element in `b` is *O(1)* but the worst-case is *O(n)* size n constant.

Answer (score 0):

actually searching for a value in a list is an O(n) complexity so the second solution is worse since its O(n^2)
while searching for a key in dictionary is O(1) so the first solution is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: O(|a| + |b|)
Solution 2: O(|a| * |b|)

And solution 1 should use a set, not a dict.